# How do you render the View, Edit, Delete, and Revisions tabs in a specific location on node/page?

Tags: 8, theming

What is the Drupal 8 equivalent of the following code?

```
<?php if (!empty($tabs)): ?>
<?php print render($tabs); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't want/prefer `{{ content }}` as there are other fields in the page which get rendered at the same position and corrupt my template.

Comment: I found the answer as following:
1.) As i was doing a custom theme based on bootstrap cdn staterkit, it could not render tabs off the bat. so i created a region tabs in <theme>.info.yml.
2.) I created a block using tabs "core" module into the tabs region.
3.)Used {{ page['tabs'] }} to render tab region.
Thanks for all the help, you guys are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found the answer as following:* 
1.) As i was doing a custom theme based on bootstrap cdn staterkit, it could not render tabs off the bat. so i created a region tabs in `<theme>.info.yml`.

2.) I created a block using tabs "core" module into the tabs region.

3.)Used `{{ page['tabs'] }}` to render tab region. 
**Thanks for all the help, you guys are the best.**

Answer (score 3):

The tabs are in a block now. Go to the block layout (/admin/structure/block) and move the block **Tabs** to another position.

If you don't find an existing region for what you want to do, add a new region to your theme and place this region in the page template **page--node.html.twig**, so that you can integrate the tabs inside of your html structure. If you need the tabs in different positions you can add multiple instances of the tabs block and configure the visibility.

Try not to put tabs in nodes, combine those two on the page level in a custom page template for nodes if possible.

But, in case you need them between the content of the node. you can do it on node.html.twig. It is not the best practice but can be done if required, but you need to take care, that the caching is working and that the tabs don't appear when the node is used in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) you can render blocks inside node templates. For example to ***render the primary tabs block*** use:

```
{{ drupal_block('local_tasks_block') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the *bartik_local_tasks* block (for the Bartik theme) inside your theme block placement.

- Visit /admin/structure/block.
- Select your theme from the tabs panel; for example select *bartik* from the panel

  > [image: screenshot]
- Move the *tabs* block in the theme block placement up/down to set it for all

  > [image: screenshot]

Note: Moving the *tabs* block up/down will move this block for all the content and all the content types using that theme.

There is a programmatic way to do this.

- Create a custom tag block inside modules/[module-name]/src/Plugin/Block directory where you create View, Edit, Delete, and Revisions tabs
- Create the TwigExtension.php file inside modules/[module-name]/src
- Use this extension in the theme

  ```
  function hook_preprocess_node($variables) {
    $abc = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('{block_name}',[]);
    $variables['custom_tabs_block'] = $abc->build();
  }
  ```
- Use this variable inside your node.html.twig

Alternatively, you can write your preprocess function, for example   `hooks_preprocess_page(){}` for page.html.twig, where you can check the node content type and other fields, and set a variable.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['type'] = '';

  if (isset($variables['node']->get('type')->target_id) && $variables['node']->get('type')->target_id == 'articles') {
    $variables['type'] = 'articles';
  }
}
```

This variable will be available for in the node.html.twig file.

```
{%if type == 'articles' %}
  You are watching an {{ type }} content.
{% else %}
  You are visiting a non-article content.
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent twig code is as follows

```
{% if tabs %}
  {{ tabs }}
{% endif %}
```